# Python - Lark - Grammar - Can not generate AST

Tags: python, syntax, tree, grammar, lark-parser

i am currently trying to generate an abstract syntax tree from a functional expression, which could be for example:

```
OR(FunctionOne("valueA", "valueB", "valueC"), FunctionTwo("valueD", "valueE", "valueF"))
```

Basically a simple concatenation of operators(AND | OR) and their functions(can be nested).

I would like to transfer this string to an abstract syntax tree, e.g. :

```
value
  OR
    FunctionOne:
      value1: valueA
      value2: valueB
      value3: valueC
    FunctionTwo:
      value4: valueD
      value5: valueE
      value6: valueF
```

What i did so far...

from lark import Lark

```
parser = Lark(r"""
    value: operator

    operator : operatorvalue"("function"(how_to_handle_params)"*")"
    operatorvalue : "OR" | "AND"

    function : "FunctionOne" | "FunctionTwo"

    """, start='value')
```

Can anybody help me out with this issue?

Just need some starting point, as docs only handle json...

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should try to represent the responsibility of each entity in syntax. So, for example, a function contains its own arguments:

```
function: NAME "(" params? ")"

params: (NAME ","?)+
```

Lark has plenty of example grammars, such as a [calculator](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/examples/calc.py), [Python](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/examples/python3.lark), and [Lark (its own syntax)](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/examples/lark.lark)